# Databuilder pattern issue

Tags: c#, builder-pattern

I am playing with data builder pattern, and I am failing to understand some behaviours. 
I wrote this simplified version of what I am trying to achieve below

```
    public abstract class DataBuilderParent
    {
        private MyParent myParent;

        protected void SetDataBuilder(MyParent myParent)
        {
            this.myParent = myParent;
        }

        public DataBuilderParent WithId(int id)
        {
            myParent.Id = id;
            return this;
        }
    }

    public class DataBuilderChild : DataBuilderParent
    {
        private readonly MyChild myChild = new MyChild();

        public DataBuilderChild()
        {
            base.SetDataBuilder(myChild);
        }

        public DataBuilderChild WithDescription(string description)
        {
            myChild.Description = description;
            return this;
        }

        private MyChild Build()
        {
            return myChild;
        }

        public static implicit operator MyChild(DataBuilderChild dataBuilder)
        {
            return dataBuilder.Build();
        }
    }

    public class MyParent
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyChild : MyParent
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Usage of the code above

```
   internal class Program
   {
     private static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        MyChild child = new DataBuilderChild().WithDescription("");
     }
   }
```

Now it will create the child for me, also the intellisense shows up that I can do this new DataBuilderChild().WithId(1).WithDescription("");
however when I try to build it fails. I do not understand why I am not able to access this method ? it is public and its visible by the intellisense. 
Can anybody explain how to make it work please?
Thank you

**EDIT**

The error message is: Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'TestProgram.Program.DataBuilderParent' to 'TestProgram.Program.MyChild' C:\Apps\TestProgram\Program.cs  44  29  TestProgram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just refactored my answer from the comments.

```
public class MyParent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class MyChild : MyParent
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Make the WithDescription method in the `DataBuilderParent` class as `abstract`.

```
public abstract class DataBuilderParent
{
    private MyParent myParent;

    protected void SetDataBuilder(MyParent myParent)
    {
        this.myParent = myParent;
    }

    public DataBuilderParent WithId(int id)
    {
        myParent.Id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public abstract DataBuilderParent WithDescription(string description);

    private MyChild BuildAsChild()
    {
        return myParent as MyChild;
    }

    private MyParent Build()
    {
        return myParent;
    }

    public static implicit operator MyChild(DataBuilderParent dataBuilder)
    {
        return dataBuilder.BuildAsChild();
    }

    public static implicit operator MyParent(DataBuilderParent dataBuilder)
    {
        return dataBuilder.Build();
    }
}
```

Then the `DataBuilderChild`

```
public class DataBuilderChild : DataBuilderParent
{
    private readonly MyChild myChild = new MyChild();

    public DataBuilderChild()
    {
        base.SetDataBuilder(myChild);
    }

    public override DataBuilderParent WithDescription(string description)
    {
        myChild.Description = description;
        return this;
    }

    private MyChild Build()
    {
        return myChild;
    }

    public static implicit operator MyChild(DataBuilderChild dataBuilder)
    {
        return dataBuilder.Build();
    }
}
```

You would then build like this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var childBuilder = new DataBuilderChild().WithId(1).WithDescription("Child");

        MyParent parent = childBuilder;

        MyChild child = childBuilder;

        Console.WriteLine(@"Parent With Id {0}", parent.Id);

        Console.WriteLine(@"Child With Id {0} and Desciprtion - {1}", child.Id, child.Description);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `WithId` is `DataBuilderParent`, which does not define the method `WithDescription`; this is only defined in the derived class `DataBuilderChild`. Apparently you aim at having some Named Constructor idiom on a class hierarchy, which cannot be implemented this way.

Furthermore, `DataBuilderParent` does not define a cast operator, neither to `MyChild` nor to `MyParent`, whereas `DataBuilderChild` defeines a cast operator to `MyChild`, as stated in the error message.

Comment: WithDescription sets up the value properly for the child, its the WithId which does not compile :(

Comment: Please see the Edit part of my question, for the error message.

Comment: like @Codor mentioned `WithDescription` is only available in the DataBuilderChild class whereas the `WithId` returns object of type `DataBuilderParent` so when you do WithId("1") it returns `DataBuilderParent` on which you are trying `WithDescription` which is only defined in the child type.
you can try
 `((DataBuilderChild)(new DataBuilderChild().WithId("1"))).WithDescription("description");`

Comment: @Vignesh.N hi, thank you very much, this cast works :), if you make it as an answer I'll accept it.